# I need to make discount depends from Registration date (i.e. 3% discount to Opportunity when Account registered 1-2 years ago, 5% 2-3 years ago)

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
    Account parentAccount = parentAccountsMap.get(opp.AccountId);
    if(parentAccount.Registration_Date__c != null){
        Date todayDate = Date.today();
        Date RegDay = parentAccount.Registration_Date__c;
        Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate);
        if(numberOfDays >= 365 || numberOfDays < 730 ){
            for (DiscountAmount__mdt disc : DiscountRecords){
                if(disc.Years_Since_Reg__c == 1){
                    opp.Amount = opp.Amount - (opp.Amount*(disc.AccountDiscount__c / 100));
                }
            }
        }
        if(numberOfDays >= 730 || numberOfDays < 1095 ){
            for (DiscountAmount__mdt disc : DiscountRecords){
                if(disc.Years_Since_Reg__c == 2){
                    opp.Amount = opp.Amount - (opp.Amount*(disc.AccountDiscount__c / 100));
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

when i create Opp with Acc with reg date 2.3 years ago i have two discounts. How can i fix this?
Thanks, Andrii

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

Instead of using `OR` (`||`) logic in your `if` statements, change them to `AND` (`&&`) logic.

`OR` logic is just that - allows for *either/any* of the conditions to be TRUE to enter the `if` block.

With the way you have it, say, for example, that the `numberOfDays` is 750. 750 is `>= 365` so it will enter the first `if` block. But since 750 is also `>= 730` it will also enter the second `if` block.

`AND` logic requires that *ALL* conditions are TRUE to enter the `if` block.

Changing it to

```
if (numberOfDays >= 365 && numberOfDays < 730 )
```

will limit it.

Do the same for the second `if` to restrict it to that window of numbers of days.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic right now has several fundamental flaws. Moonpie pointed out the issue with your `if` statements, but there is more.

Regardless of the account age, your inner `for` loops are applying *all* discounts.

You don't need an inner loop, you need to select *one* of your `DiscountAmount__mdt` records, based on the age of the account. You could use a loop, but I believe it'd be much better for you to use a `Map` so you can say "this account is 1 year old, get the 1 year discount record".

My suggested changes:

- Make the Account age a *formula field* (so you don't need to do the work in Apex). you could do something like `FLOOR(<sub-expression for # of days> / 365)` to get a result in integer number of years.
- Make a `Map<String, DiscountAmount__mdt>`, and loop over your discount records to populate the map (something like `myMap.put('1 year', discountRecord)`). This should be done outside of the `for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){` loop. A `Map<Integer, DiscountAmount__mdt>` may allow you to remove all of the `if` and `else` inside your loop over Opportunity
- Figure out which discount (a single discount) needs to be applied
- After you know which discount to apply, apply it to the current `Opportunity` you're working on
- Don't overcomplicate the discount application, `opp.Amount *= (1 - <discount %>)` is all you should need. This is equivalent to `opp.Amount = opp.Amount * (1 - <discount %>)`, which itself is equivalent to what you currently have `amount = amount - (amount * <discount %>)`.

Comment: That's what I get for being hyperfocused and only answering the question that was asked, not the question that needed to be answered.

Comment: @Moonpie if it's any consolation, I missed the issue with the operator used in the `if` statements until you pointed it out. The nested `for` loops and the largely repeated code in both `if` blocks is what caught my eye.